# Extracting value from object after comparing arrays IDs, Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile

I have 2 things I want to compare and return a list of Strings for each of the matching Ids with the corresponding names. Example: I have a list of "genre_ids": [16, 878, 28] from a movie, and from another API I get a list of objects with id and name of the genres, { "id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction" }. Now I want to compare the list of genre_ids with the list of objects with ids and names and return a List of names with all the matching Ids. How do I do that? I tried using the `.where()` option but failed miserably.

JSON from genre list:

```
{
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 28,
            "name": "Action"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Adventure"
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "Animation"
        },
        {
            "id": 35,
            "name": "Comedy"
        },
        {
            "id": 10749,
            "name": "Romance"
        },
        {
            "id": 878,
            "name": "Science Fiction"
        },
    ]
}
```

JSON from movie list:

```
"results": [
{
            "adult": false,
            "genre_ids": [
                16,
                878,
                28
            ],
            "id": 610150,
            "release_date": "2022-06-11",
            "title": "Dragon Ball Super: Super Hero",
            "vote_average": 7.5,
            "vote_count": 126
        },
]
```

Both models from the APIs:

```
class Movies {
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? overview;
  List<dynamic>? genreIds;
  dynamic voteAverage;
  String? posterPath;

  Movies({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.overview,
    this.genreIds,
    this.voteAverage,
    this.posterPath,
  });

  Movies.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    overview = json['overview'];
    genreIds = json['genre_ids'].toList();
    voteAverage = json['vote_average'];
    posterPath = json['poster_path'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = id;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['overview'] = overview;
    data['vote_average'] = voteAverage;
    data['genre_ids'] = genreIds;
    data['poster_path'] = posterPath;
    return data;
  }
}

class Genres {
  int? id;
  String? name;

  Genres({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  Genres.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'] as String;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = id;
    data['name'] = name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

API calls:

```
Future<List<Movies?>> getAllMovies() async {

    Response response = await Dio().get(Contants().moviesUrl);

    return (response.data['results'] as List).map((movies) {
      return Movies.fromJson(genres);
    }).toList();
  }


 Future<List<Genres?>> getAllGenres() async {
    Response response = await Dio().get(Contants().genresUrl);

    return (response.data['genres'] as List).map((genres) {
      return Genres.fromJson(genres);
    }).toList();
  }
```

Future builder:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.wait([
          RepositoryFromAPItoDB().gettAllMovies(),
          RepositoryFromAPItoDB().getAllGenres()
        ]),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>?> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data?[0].length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return MoviesListTile(
                  title: snapshot.data?[0][index].title,
                  voteAverage: snapshot.data?[0][index].voteAverage,
                  description: snapshot.data?[0][index].overview,
                  posterPath: snapshot.data?[0][index].posterPath,
                  genreIds: snapshot.data?[0][index].genreIds,
                  genres: ['drama', 'somehting'],
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
```

Requested output of names from the list:

```
Widget getTextWidgets(List<String?> strings) {
    return Row(
        children: strings
            .map((item) => Container(
                      child: Text(
                        item!,
                       ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            .toList());
  }
```

Any form of help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the requested output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> genres = {
    "genres": [
      {"id": 28, "name": "Action"},
      {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"},
      {"id": 16, "name": "Animation"},
      {"id": 35, "name": "Comedy"},
      {"id": 10749, "name": "Romance"},
      {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"},
    ]
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> movie = {
    "adult": false,
    "genre_ids": [16, 878, 28],
    "id": 610150,
    "release_date": "2022-06-11",
    "title": "Dragon Ball Super: Super Hero",
    "vote_average": 7.5,
    "vote_count": 126
  };

  print(getGenres(movie, genres["genres"]));
}

List getGenres(Map movie, List genres) {
  final Set movieGenreIds = Set.from(movie["genre_ids"]);
  return genres
      .where((g) => movieGenreIds.contains(g["id"]))
      .map((g) => g["name"])
      .toList();
}
```

The output:

```
[Action, Animation, Science Fiction]
```

Edit, using the models you provided.

```
List getGenres(Movie movie, List<Genre> genres) {
  final Set movieGenreIds = Set.from(movie.genreIds);
  return genres
      .where((g) => movieGenreIds.contains(g.id))
      .map((g) => g.name)
      .toList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an error of `type 'Movies' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'`. But if I change it to not be a Map, I can't use the `Set()` option anymore.

Comment: Seems like we are talking about different objects. Can you provide a complete code example?

Comment: I just updated it. From API, to Models, JSON formats from the API and UI output with future builder..

Comment: Ok, you were very very close, so I will accept the answer but you need to update it a little. Since both models are lists, it has to be `getGenres(List<Movies> movies, List<Genres> genres)` and since you can't know where to access the list, we need an index from the data, so we need to make `getGenres` like `getGenres(List<Movies> movies, List<Genres> genres, int index)` and index is passed from the `itemBuilder` and now everything works! Thanks again mate, much appreciated!

Comment: Happy to help :) I will update the answer.
Next time I suggest you provide more context, since the models themselves are needed to provide an adequate solution.